# Why isn't Evince integrated with the HUD in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: hud, evince

With Evince running and on focus, if I press **Alt** and then type, for instance, "open" nothing comes up. Is this a bug? Something wrong with my system? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User [qamelian](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=8229) at the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191641&p=12865153#post12865153) says the following:

> Evince uses the new Gnome menu model rather than the old type that
>   appear above the app. As a result, the HUD can't communicate with
>   those menus.